# Need to move 500 specific files from one share directory to another

Tags: bash, cp, mv

I have a directory that has 50,000 files; I only need to move a subset of these files that I have in a text file. I am looking for a script/way to move these files out.

I keep finding items on how to move all files but this won't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU coreutils, you can use

```
xargs -a tomove.txt -d '\n' mv -t /path/to/destination
```

where `tomove.txt` contains the names of the files to be moved, one per line. `-d '\n'` makes sure filenames with blanks in them are interpreted properly by using newline (instead of any blank) as the filename delimiter.

`xargs` guarantees that we don't run into command line length limitations.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response when I try to run this I get the following 

mv: cannot stat â_Experienceâ: No such file or directory

Comment: @Jack I've updated the answer, your filenames might contain blanks – should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mv` command. In the following example I move entries in list.txt from the directory old to the directory new.

```
$ mkdir old new
$ touch old/{a,b,c}.{sh,c,txt}
$ echo "a.sh
c.txt
b.c" > list.txt
$ cd old/
$ mv $(cat ../list.txt) ../new
$ find ../new/
../new/
../new/a.sh
../new/c.txt
../new/b.c
```